# Show the list of dates from the area

Tags: t-sql

Maybe somebody can help me, I have select:

```
SELECT  p.pers_name + ' ' + p.pers_lastname ,
        a.hol_from ,
        a.hol_to ,
        ( DATEDIFF(day, a.at_nuo, a.at_iki) ) + 1 AS [Holidays days] ,
        YEAR(a.hol_from) AS Eayrs
FROM    dba.holidays AS a
        INNER JOIN dba.work AS d ON a.work_id = d.work
        INNER JOIN dba.pers AS p ON d.pers_id = p.pers_id
WHERE   p.pers_vard = 'Name'
        AND p.pers_pav = 'Lastname'
ORDER BY Eayrs DESC
```

This query result:

```
Name Lastname 2014-02-05 00:00:00   2014-02-07 00:00:00 3   2014
Name Lastname 2014-01-20 00:00:00   2014-01-23 00:00:00 4   2014
```

I have 3 day of holidays and 4 day of holidays in second raw. How I can get it?

```
Name Lastname 2014-02-05 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-02-06 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-02-07 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-01-20 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-01-21 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-01-22 00:00:00
Name Lastname 2014-01-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: You need to build and join to a calendar table.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do this is by joining your query to a calendar table where you have all the dates in the range you need (e.g. 365 rows one for each date)

```
SELECT  pers_name ,
        pers_lastname ,
        c.calendardate
FROM    ( SELECT    p.pers_name + ' ' + p.pers_lastname ,
                    a.hol_from ,
                    a.hol_to ,
                    ( DATEDIFF(day, a.at_nuo, a.at_iki) ) + 1 AS [Holidays days] ,
                    YEAR(a.hol_from) AS Eayrs
          FROM      dba.holidays AS a
                    INNER JOIN dba.work AS d ON a.work_id = d.work
                    INNER JOIN dba.pers AS p ON d.pers_id = p.pers_id
          WHERE     p.pers_vard = 'Name'
                    AND p.pers_pav = 'Lastname'
          ORDER BY  Eayrs DESC
        ) t
        INNER JOIN Calendar c ON c.calendardate BETWEEN hol_from AND hol_to
```